# ModelValidation on posted action parameter not happening

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

Why doesn't ASP.NET Core validate `[FromBody]` attributed action parameters? In the example below the paramter `value` of type `SomeClass` does not get validated. It doesn't even appear in the ModelState dictionary (only `id`). `this.ModelState.IsValid` is always `true`, even though the Name property is set to a string longer than 2 letters.

Even `TryValidateModel` is always `true` no matter what the request body contains (JSON).

[Sample Repo here](https://github.com/MarcusKohnert/FromBodyModelValidation)

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvcCore()
            .AddJsonFormatters();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

and

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult Put(
            int id,
            [FromBody]SomeClass value)
        {
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid == false)
                throw new Exception();

            if (this.TryValidateModel(value) == false)
                throw new Exception();

            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        [StringLength(2)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register MVC data annotation. It is not added by default when you use the light `AddMvcCore` method instead of `AddMvc`. Modify your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services
   .AddMvcCore()
   .AddJsonFormatters()
   .AddDataAnnotations(); // add this line
```