# Model Validation using StringLength validation attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, model-validation

In my ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1.1 I've a form with one input as follows where user is required to enter the district code as two characters such as 01, 02,...10,11, etc. But when I submit the form by entering district code as, say, 123, it still successfully submits the form without forcing user to enter the district code as two characters. What I may be missing?

**MyViewModels**

```
...
[Display(Name = "District"),StringLength(2)]
public string Dist { get; set; }
...
```

**Form**

```
@model MyProj.Models.MyViewModel
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Dist" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input asp-for="Dist" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Dist" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-pull-8">01 to 53 — district codes</div>
</div>
...
```

**NOTE**
I am using default `ASP.NET Core Web Application` template with latest version of VS2017 that by default installs necessary Bootstrap and other javascripts when one uses such template.

Comment: Have you added the client javascript for validation? Try to check, in the server (action) is the ModelState is valid and if the invalid check if the reason is the Dist Property, if it says it is invalid what happens is that you are not validating at the client (javascript)

Comment: @dime2lo I've added a **NOTE** in the post above to answer your question that other readers may have as well.

Comment: have you checked how the model is arriving at the server (if ModelState is valid)? If is invalid, as it should be, then the problem is in the client. Maybe I´m wrong but you have to add the section for javascript client side validation. `@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}`

Comment: how do you register the MVC middleware( `.AddMvc` or `.AddMvcCore`). I am asking cause MVC data annotation services should be registered and this is done automatically only with `AddMVC`, otherwise you need directly call  `AddMvcCore().AddDataAnnotations()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44979691/2833802

Comment: @Set The `ConfigureServices(...)` in `StartUp.cs` has `AddMvc();` in it.

Comment: @dime2lo Is the following for partial view only: `@section Scripts { @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); } }`. My view is not a partial view.

Answer (score 4):

1 - The first parameter of StringLength is Maximum length. To define minimum you can do:

```
    [Display(Name = "District")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Dist { get; set; }
```

or:

```
    [Display(Name = "District")]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string Dist { get; set; }
```

2. The Required attribute is missing!

**View**

Validation script:

```
@section Scripts { @Html.Partial("_ValidationScriptsPartial") }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Contact(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { ... }
```